# How can I make my ScrollViewer pass Click events through to the control behind it?

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollviewer, mouseclick-event

I have two grids overlaying one another, and the top layer is in a ScrollViewer. The problem is the bottom layer has click events, and they don't get triggered with the ScrollViewer there.

Is there a way to have the ScrollViewer pass click events to the control behind it?

```
<Grid>
    <local:MyBackgroundControlWithClickEvents />
    <ScrollViewer>
        <local:MyForegroundControlWithClickEvents />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click events [bubble up the visual tree to the root](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx), because your control is not a parent of the `ScrollViewer`, it will not receive these events. I know they might overlap on screen, but as far as the visual tree is concerned they are siblings, not parent / child.

To make this work, you could change `MyBackgroundControlWithClickEvents` into a `ContentControl` and host the `ScrollViewer` within it.

Comment: My problem is both controls are two different sizes. The background one draws a grid with clickable cells and headers (which should not scroll), and the foreground control draws the grid items, which can be scrolled. Both grids are built dynamically.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that they are siblings though, and not parent/child. I might be able to rework my design to do something else.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid you are going to have to re-design. You *could* create some 'magic' of your own, adding a parent container that channels events to your sibling control.

Comment: The redesign actually worked out fine. I split up the Background ItemsControl that draws the Header and the BackgroundCells, so now I have the Header, followed by a ScrollViewer that contains both the BackgroundCells and the ForegroundItems. Needed to change some margins and borders a bit to get the same view, but worked out great